# C# split names and associate to which full name it belongs

Tags: c#, split

I am sorry if I am unable to explain my question clearly. I will try as best as I can .

I get studentsfullnames like below. They are comma seperated names which I donot have any control as of now. I just get them from service call.

studentsfullnames = "FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 and LastName2, First and Last name of S3";

Now I want to split studentsfullnames into words and associate each word with this corresponding full name like below

```
string[] splitNames = studentsfullnames.Split(' ');
```

I want relationship like below so that I will loop each splitNames and if I cannot accomodate that word on UI, I will delete the entire corresponding full name. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how I can do this. Meanwhile I am trying to see whether I can use dictionary or some other object/collection. I will post my findings/updates.

I need to write code which will identify like below

The word FirstName1 (belongs to ) FirstName1 LastName1

The word LastName1 (belongs to ) FirstName1 LastName1

The word FirstName2 (belongs to ) FirstName2 and LastName2

The word and (belongs to ) FirstName2 and LastName2

The word LastName2 (belongs to ) FirstName2 and LastName2

The word First (belongs to ) First and Last name of S3

The word and (belongs to ) First and Last name of S3

The word Last (belongs to ) First and Last name of S3

The word name (belongs to ) First and Last name of S3

The word of (belongs to ) First and Last name of S3

The word S3 (belongs to ) First and Last name of S3

Comment: so `and` is associated to `FFirst and Last name of S3` and `FirstName2 and LastName2`?

Comment: @konkked .. sorry did not get you..

Comment: You have `->` drawn from `and` to `FirstName2 and LastName2` and `FFirst and Last name of S3`, so wondering if that means the word `and` has a relationship to those two statements or if it means something else

Comment: what kind of syntax is that `FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 and LastName2, First and Last name of S3`? are they just comma-separated students, where the first and last name are separated by a single space, or is it just wrong? btw. are you sure that there will never be additional spaces in a name, thinking of e.g. Dutch names like "van den Bosch Jon", which would give four tokens instead of the expected two? Use the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option to get rid of the spaces after the commas.

Comment: Can you add an example input and desired output?

Comment: @ Bradley.. I edited my question. Please let me know is it clear

Comment: @dlatilay.. when I split van den Bosch Jon.. I get 4 tokens and now I need to write code which will tell that each token belongs to van den Bosch Jon... so by any chance I cannot fit a token on UI, I need to remove all token of van den Bosch Jon so that UI will not show van den Bosch Jon

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple with [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string names = "John Doe Jane Smith";
var matches = Regex.Matches(names, @"(?<firstName>[a-z]+)\s+(?<lastName>[a-z]+)\,*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    string firstName = match.Result("${firstName}");
    string lastName = match.Result("${lastName}");
}
```

Comment: @ returnsvoid... please see my question.. I donot get any xml tags.. I just get simple string with comma seperated...

Comment: Those aren't XML tags, they are Regex matching groups.  And please try running my code before dismissing it -- it actually works.

Comment: I ran your code. I am getting John in firstName and Doe in lastName for first looping in foreach loop. So far good. How you will know that John is part of John Doe.

Comment: The <firstName> group is capturing all characters (a-z) before a space (\s). The <lastName> group is capturing all characters (a-z) after the space (\s) but before a comma.
[This](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet) is a good resource for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this algorithm will do what you want. Which is to build up a lookup dictionary that returns a list of names that contain the word you are looking up.

```
        var studentsfullnames = "FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 and LastName2, First and Last name of S3";

        // split on full name seperated by comma
        var split1 = studentsfullnames.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // use a dict with a list. so you can key by word but have multiple strings with the same word
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        foreach (var name in split1)
        {
            var temp = name.Replace(",", "").Trim();

            // split on spaces to get individual words.
            var split2 = temp.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var word in split2)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
                    dict[word].Add(temp);
                else
                    dict.Add(word, new List<string> { temp });
            }
        }
```